# AWS Cognito Post-Confirmation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, amazon-sqs

I am using AWS Cognito for user sign-up. After sign-up confirmation I have a lambda trigger that adds the new user to my RDS instance.

My question is the following
How can I make sure that the lambda successfully adds the user to the database. My worry is that if the lambda fails I want the service to still work.

Right now, a solution I have is to add the new users to SQS using my post-confirmation lambda.

Then have lambdas that are triggered by SQS. That way even if the user add fails I still have the information to add later/see the problem.

Is this a good solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider use Cognito not only as an user sign up mechanism but a user database itself using [Cognito user pools](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools.html).

In the other side, if want to ensure that a if lambda fails, user data is not missed away, make the user sign up workflow synchronous avoiding a trigger from a cognito event. Instead, you can invoke the lambda function as a backend behind an API consumed by your frontend.

For this use case, you can think that [API gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-lambda.html) is a great option, and finally, **serverless framework** is the most valuable tool for this purpose.

By the way, your SQS solution is not bad for manage asynchronous users sign up process.

The following links could be very useful:

- [How To Create A Serverless REST API Just In Five Minutes!](https://medium.com/@alexmaisiura/how-to-create-a-serverless-rest-api-just-in-five-minutes-5beb93f57514)
- https://itnext.io/build-a-restful-api-using-aws-lambda-api-gateway-dynamodb-and-the-serverless-framework-30fc68e08a42
- [A Serverless REST API in Minutes with the Serverless Framework](https://blog.codeship.com/a-serverless-rest-api-in-minutes/)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you do mean by "My worry is that if the lambda fails I want the service to still work.".
I would assume that by code you can handle any possible error in the execution of the lambda and then log it in a custom way or just let it go and will be logged in cloudwatch. 
Either case you can configure an alarm and receive an email when something goes wrong. 
This is pretty more flexible and configurable but seems like you would not need to do something too complex.

Comment: Thanks for the response!